# On Android Mobile application using appium , how to fetch the list of web-Elements for which we need to scroll?

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

Suppose I have total Six **"remove"** button on my page.
Three are visible and for other Three I need to scroll .
When I am trying to find the total count , it is showing me the count as 3 which is visible on the screen only.
**How  to get the total count ?**
Is there any work around for that ? Scrolling by **androidUI automator** logic wont work because at any point of time only **3** "Remove" buttons can be fit to the Screen.

Answer (score 0):

As per your example,
Follow these steps:

- Get the list of elements for first three buttons, store the count in some variable:

`List<WebElement> list = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));`

(*you can use your locator strategy as per requirement*)

- Perform scroll

```
public static void scrollDown() {
        int pressX = driver.manage().window().getSize().width / 2;
        int bottomY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height * 4/5;
        int topY = driver.manage().window().getSize().height / 8;
        scroll(pressX, bottomY, pressX, topY);
    }

public static void scroll(int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {
        TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(mobileDriver);
        touchAction.longPress(PointOption.point(fromX, fromY)).moveTo(PointOption.point(toX, toY)).release().perform();
    }
```

- Again get the list of elements for the last three buttons, store the count in some variable.

`List<WebElement> list2 = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("your xpath"));`

- Calculate the count